# C# 16 bit float conversions

Tags: c#, floating-point, binary, data-conversion, 16-bit

I am using the float 16 Half type from here - 
https://gist.github.com/vermorel/1d5c0212752b3e611faf84771ad4ff0d

I have defined the following method to convert a Half value to binary string:

```
    static string HalfToBinaryString(Half value)
    {
        int bitCount = Marshal.SizeOf(value) * 8;

        string s = String.Empty;

        // value is the value you want to convert to a string (double, long, int, ...)
        foreach (byte b in Half.GetBytes(value))
        {
            s += Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'); // for hex. For binary, use 2 and 8. For octal, use 8 and 3
        }

        return s;
    }
```

And the following method to convert from binary string value to Half:

```
    static Half HalfFromBinaryString(string bstra)
    {
        int intValue = Convert.ToInt16(bstra, 2);

        return (Half)BitConverter.ToInt16(Half.GetBytes(intValue), 0);

    }
```

When I perform the following division, I get:

```
string dividend = "11001001001111111";
Half result = (Half)(Convert.ToSingle(Convert.ToInt32(dividend, 2)) / 65536.0);
var rawbits = HalfToBinaryString(result);

//result = 1.571289
//rawbits = "0100100100111110"
```

However when I perform the reverse operation, I get:

```
Half halfval = HalfFromBinaryString(rawbits);

//halfval = 29840 //(instead of 1.571289)
```

How do I convert from a 16 bit binary string representation to the correct Half value (1.571289)?

Comment: Where did resultdbl4 come from?

Comment: sorry, edited to the correct variable.

Comment: Your HalfToBinaryString method is super inefficient, by the way

Comment: I do not unterstand the meaning of your code. There is already a `GetBytes(half)` and a `ToHalf(Byte[])` method in the provided repo.

Comment: I want to store the result of a division in Half variable, then convert that Half value to floating-point 16-bit binary string representation. Finally I want to do the reverse operation of that 16-bit binary string into its Half value.

Comment: After conversion to a binary string, how do you know where the decimal point was?

Comment: @CaiusJard There is a fixed number of bits for the mantissa and a fixed number of bits for the exponent. The exponent tells you where the decimal point is. Isn't that how floating point numbers work?

Comment: What I was getting at is by treating it as an int, the OP moves the decimal point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `HalfFromBinaryString` is wrong, because your code is really just interpreting the string as an `int` in binary, and casting that `int` to a `Half` and returning. You could simplify your return line to `return (Half)intValue;` and it will still do the same thing.

Since the `Half` struct provides you with a `ToHalf(ushort)` method, you can use it to create a `Half`. Essentially, parse the string as a `ushort`, and pass the `ushort` into `ToHalf`:

```
ushort bits = Convert.ToUInt16(bstra, 2);
return Half.ToHalf(bits);
```

Your `HalfToBinaryString` method can also be simplified, as `Half` also provides the reverse operation of `ToHalf` - `GetBits`:

```
ushort bits = Half.GetBits(value);
return Convert.ToString(bits, 2).PadLeft(16, '0');
```

Comment: When I do this operation, I am getting the return value as "10.48438", instead of "1.571289".

Comment: @usrso What about rewriting `HalfToBinaryString` like I said in my answer as well? I feel like it could be an issue of endianness...